# Trouble with alignat environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, alignat

What a shame!  After years of using LaTeX, I'm still truggling with the pesky **alignat** environment which I don't understand.  Here's a MWE showing what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla :
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad y \sim z,
    & a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad b\sim c, \\
    x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad xyz \sim z,
    & a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad 5b \sim c,
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

I need to get a large space on the red line, so each column is well balanced to the left and to the right.  I need the arrows and the tildes to be aligned, without changing the space around them.

I know this should be very basic, but I don't get it!  :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are. I added a spacing of 4em. Anyway, you only need three alignment columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla :
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & y&\sim z,&\hspace{4em}
    a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & 4b & \sim c, \\
    x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & xyz & \sim z,&
     a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & b & \sim xyzc,
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow, so the space should be by hand! I was trying to do automatically, like `align` does.

Comment: No, alignat gives you full control on the alignment columns spacing

Comment: Why the \hspace{4em} spacing?

Comment: I understood you wanted a large spacing between the two groups. Isn't it so?

Comment: yes, this is what I need, but it's still not clear to me how this is working.  Also, if you change the last term (b \sim c) to something like $4 b \sim xyzc$, it isn't aligned anymore.

Comment: Apparently, adding a column to the alignat environment does the trick:
  
 \begin{alignat*}{4}
  x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & y &\sim z,
  &\hspace{4em}
  a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & b &\sim c, \\
  x \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & xyz &\sim z,
  &\hspace{4em}
  a \quad &\Rightarrow \quad & 5b &\sim xyzc,
 \end{alignat*}

Comment: If you want to align the `\sim` signs, you indeed need 4 columns (see my edited answer). The way  `alignat` works is like `align`, but it doesn't add  any spacing between the columns: any spacing has to be added by hand, at the relevant place. The `&`s  with even index mark the start of a new alignment column and the following `&` (odd index) marks  the alignment point of its column.  What is on the left  of the alignment point is right-aligned, and what is on the right is left-aligned, with proper spacing.

Comment: @Bernard, you said *it doesn't add any spacing between the columns: any spacing has to be added by hand* and finally, I fully understand `alignat`. Thanks a lot.